# Remove support for iPhone with new updated version of app

Tags: ios, app-store

We released few versions of our app with universal support ( i.e. app is supported both on iPhone and iPad). Now with new version of our app (1.14) we want that this version should be available to iPad only. This means 1.14 should be available only on iPad and iPhone user may not able to install it. But when we change setting in Xcode from Universal to iPad only it gives error while uploading ipa to app store that if previous version of app supported iPhone then in updated version of app we cannot remove iPhone support. Now we are looking for solution to this problem. Please guide us what are way to over come this issue. Due to this issue we have to delay our app release so kindly give us possible suggestions as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way of doing what you want. Apple deliberately don't want you removing functionality for existing users.

Maybe the only way forward is to remove your current app from sale and submit a new, iPad-only version. You'll lose your reviews, sales rank, etc.